# Bending Metal with soft body

Tags: modifiers, soft-body

I am trying to follow this tutorial.
[crushing-metal-tutorial](https://davidzerba.wordpress.com/2012/09/30/crushing-metal-tutorial/)

I'm wanting to simulating two metal doors being smashed in.

Following along the tutorial, I make a low poly cage mesh for each door and configure the collison objects and the soft body modifier to each door.

The simulation perfoms as instructed. However I'm unable to complete the tutorial and get the desired effect that I want as the mesh deform modifier isn't bending the high-poly doors to the shape of the cage meshes.

> Add the “Mesh Deform” modifier.
>
> Now that we have the physics all set up, we want to make it affect our hi-poly object. Unhide it by pressing Alt+H and move it to match up with the cage mesh’s new position. To make it get affected by the cage mesh, you need to add a “Mesh Deform” modifier.
>
> A “Mesh Deform” modifier allows a certain mesh to control how an object deforms. For the “Object”, choose your cage mesh. The “Precision” amount is how accurate the binding is. The higher it is, the more accurate, but it also takes longer to calculate. I usually just put it at “4”. Now just press “Bind”.

My intact doors do not follow the cage mesh shape when I bind them.
[image: odd mesh deform]
parts of the original doors are welded to the floor plain when I run the simulation with the binded mesh.

[image: cage at resting spot]

With the modifier applied the 'high'-poly mesh has strecthed vertices from the start to end of the simulation. The final frames of the simulation also doesn't apply the deformation to the doors.

What is the correct steps to apply the deformation of the cage to the high-poly doors?